# Android : How to create a list that contains expandable rows

Tags: android, listview, expand

I am new to Android and want to create a ListView that contains another list inside it. On touch of the outer listview item it should expand or collapse its child list.
(Something similar to collapse in Bootstrap)
Is it possible to do this in Android?

Comment: Have you tried using an `ExpandableListView`?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you have tried. But it is possible in Android using a widget called ExpandableListView. [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/) is a good example to get you started.
Also check the official [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html).

Comment: This example is quite simple and useful. Thankyou! :)

Comment: Glad to help! Please accept this answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `ExpandableListView` which is a `View` that shows items in a vertically scrolling two-level list. This differs from the `ListView` by allowing two levels: groups which can individually be expanded to show its children. The items come from the `ExpandableListAdapter` associated with this view.

**Official documentation for `ExpandableListView`**:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

**Example of `ExpandableListView` within a `ScrollView`**:

http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/expandable-listview-inside-scrollview/